# Maximum increment to sbrk

Tags: c, linux, memory

What is the upper limit of the increment that can be used in a `sbrk` call?

I am unable to successfully call `sbrk` with a `2e10` increment, but I am able to call `sbrk` with a `1e10` increment three times in a row.

I have a similar issue with `mmap`.

Tested in a Arch Linux 5.4.3-arch1-1 x86-64 with glibc 2.30.
Code example compiled with gcc 9.2.0.

Code example:

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("sizeof(intptr_t)=%ld\n", sizeof(intptr_t));

    intptr_t increment = 1e10;
    if (sbrk(increment * 2) == (void *) -1) {
        printf("error sbrk 1\n");
    }
    if (sbrk(increment) == (void *) -1) {
        printf("error sbrk 2\n");
    }
    if (sbrk(increment) == (void *) -1) {
        printf("error sbrk 3\n");
    }
    if (sbrk(increment) == (void *) -1) {
        printf("error sbrk 4\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code above results in the following output:

```
sizeof(intptr_t)=8
error sbrk 1
```

Comment: The answer probably depends on your flavor and version of operating system, often, one chunk cannot be more than 2GB minus a small amount.

Comment: @Aganju 1e10 are nearly 10GB.

Comment: @Aganju I updated the question with more information about the test environment: Tested in a Arch Linux 5.4.3-arch1-1 x86-64 with glibc 2.30. Code example compiled with gcc 9.2.0.

Comment: why mess with `sbrk()`?   The MAN page for the function says to use `malloc()` instead.

Comment: @user3629249 `malloc` and `mmap` have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, sbrk will take `intptr_t` on most modern systems. This will be 32 signed int quantity (-2^31 to 2^31-1) when compiling with 32 bit pointers, and 64 bit signed int (-2^63 to 2^63-1) when compiling with 64 bit pointers.

Of course, the practical range is much smaller. For the sbrk call to succeed the following should be true:

- The parameter should be within the address space supported by the processor/machine. Many modern system will allow up to 2^48 addresses (as oppose to the theoretical limit of 2^64.
- The total size of requested heap size should be within the configuration limits: the process specific hard/soft limits (ulimit), and system configuration limit.
- When increasing size of heap, there should be enough physical or swap space to supported the requested memory.

Back to the user question, when running 32 bit program (on 32 or 64 system), the limit is 2GB or less. And 1e10 will not work. When running 64 bit program the request may fail or pass depending on configuration, resources and setup.

Answer (score 0):

I did more experiments to try to check what configurations and resources could explain the described behavior.

I found out that I am unable to allocate a **contiguous** block of memory larger than the total physical Memory + Swap.
This seems to answer my question.

However, this is a configuration?